# Is there an recommended text for the difference between what people say and what they do?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

trld; I’m interested in the philosophical difference between ‘what people say’ and ‘what people do’, where can I find an *introductory* text that discusses this.

I’m aware the following are generic homespun wisdom and I think they have use:

Actions speak louder than words.
Pay attention to what someone does, not what they say.

And that’s a pretty obvious thing in cases like ‘He says he loves me, but he hits me’, and “says that he’s for freedom, but votes for warrantees wiretapping”.  I do believe that actions have a significantly greater impact that words but I haven’t got much of a framework for thinking about how edge cases like writers (and philosophers), protests and the like fit in. I’m looking for the right things to google for so I can get to a discussion of the topic.  Right now I haven’t got a scaffold to start from.

Comment: I don't see how this is a philosophical problem. As it stands, this question appears to be off-topic because it is about social sciences or psychology, rather than philosophy.

Comment: Sartre calls this "bad faith" a term he's actually getting from Hegel's unhappy consciousness.

Comment: philosophy doesn't talk about hypocrisy, hahah OK

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy talks about EVERYTHING

Here's a Yale Lecture PHIL 181: PHILOSOPHY AND THE SCIENCE OF HUMAN NATURE

Lecture 2 - The Ring of Gyges: Morality and Hypocrisy

http://oyc.yale.edu/philosophy/phil-181/lecture-2#ch2

I didn't watch it, but it may work as a starting point.

Comment: Downloading for a conveniently long train journey today - will come back and vote :)